# write the code higher order function instead of usual loops/iterators

Tags: scala

Can anyone tell me how to write this below code using higher order functions.

```
var x = 10
while (x < =10)
{
if (x <= 5)
print(x)
x = x+1
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not compile, and even when I make it compile it does not do anything because your while condition is only true once: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/mH4Gvwv/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or using the "sugar" to create Range:

```
(0 to 10)
.filter(_ <= 5)
.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the piece of code you provided looked something like this:

```
var x = 0

while (x <= 10) {

  if (x <= 5) println(x)

  x = x + 1
}
```

Then, using higher order functions (I would just call it functional programming), it could look something like this:

```
List.range(0, 10)
  .filter(_ <= 5)
  .foreach(println)
```

Of course this combination of `.range()` and `.filter()` could be simplified to `.range(0, 5)`.

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/mH4Gvwv/1)

I hope that helps.